# parsing JSON which contains "objects"

Tags: python, json

I'm getting data from an application that returns what seems to be an JSON, but with some "objects". For instance:

```
{"rgEvtData":[new VisData(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,3,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,4,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,5,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,6,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,7,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,8,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1)]}
```

any idea if I can parse it on python without dirty workarounds (ie, replace() or regexp)?

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Seeing how that's - and for good reason - invalid JSON, somehow I doubt you'll have much luck finding a builtin library. Is beating the authors of the original application with a stick out of the question?

Comment: I haven't heard the beating with a stick approach before but it makes sense in this case, as the whole idea of a proprietary format for cases like this is ridiculous.  It looks like whoever wrote this assumed their users would be getting this data via JavaScript and `eval`-ing it.  *Shudders*.  How are you getting this data into your Python application?

Comment: @millimoose, well, I'm guessing they live in Redmond, so it's a bit far away from me :(

Comment: to be fair, I'm kinda "reversing engineering" Outlook Web App, so I can't exactly blame them for using this format :P

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.
Even if python could parse it, what would it do with the `VisData`s?

I think your only option (except the stick approach mentioned), to translate this string into valid JSON somehow. For example, replacing `new VisData(...)` with `[...]`, or `{"class": "VisData", "args": [...]}` if you have multiple classnames. But you said you don't want that.

**Update**
I have an example, I think it is what you need.
It handles custom classes in the format you provided.
It would also handle multiple classes and any number/type of constructor arguments.

```
import re
import json

# our python VisData class
class VisData(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

# object hook to convert our {"class":"VisData","args":[...]} dict to VisData insances
def object_hook(obj):
    # if we recognize our object describer dict
    if len(obj) == 2 and "class" in obj and "args" in obj:
        # instantiate our classes by name
        clazz = globals()[obj["class"]]
        args = obj["args"]
        return clazz(*args)
    return obj

# input
input_string = '{"rgEvtData":[new VisData(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1),new VisData(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1)]}'

# make it json
json_string = re.sub(r'new (\w+)\(([^\)]*)\)', r'{"class":"\1","args":[\2]}', input_string)

# parse it with our object hook
data = json.loads(json_string, object_hook=object_hook)

# result
print(data)                         # -> {u'rgEvtData': [<__main__.VisData object at 0x1065d8210>, <__main__.VisData object at 0x1065d8250>]}
print(data["rgEvtData"][0])         # -> <__main__.VisData object at 0x1065d8210>
print(data["rgEvtData"][0].args)    # -> (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1)
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to create a VisData class on python and it be able to convert it to an object of this class, but I knew it was a long shot :(

Comment: If you create the `VisData` class in python, then you can easily instantiate that based on the class&args dicts in the parsed object I mentioned.

Comment: Have you been able to check my example?